# fluentd How to concatenate long logs (>16K are split)

Tags: kubernetes, logging, fluentd

We occasionally have a log message greater than 16K that when scraped by fluentd and forwarded to Elasticsearch will appear as two separate documents. This often happens with Java exceptions/stack traces being logged.

How can I configure fluentd to concatenate the separate logs into one log message before forwarding to Elasticsearch?

Google searching has pointed out using the "concat" filter but I'm struggling to find good documentation or an example of how I can get all the fields correct. We are using the "tail" source to parse docker logs. If someone can help with the configuration needed to support the long logs that get split, that would be most helpful.  We are running fleuntd version 1.15.3 as a container in Kubernetes.

I don't have a great staging environment at the moment so haven't tried anything.  If someone can point me to a good example, I will update the fluentd configuration and then figure out how I can force an exception to test the log forward to elasticsearch on a long log split into multiple documents.

Comment: Are you currently using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions?

Comment: No, we are not.  We are running fluentd in our on-prem kubernetes cluster and deploying using bitnami helm charts.  So, we aren't running any plugins that aren't native to fluentd.  I'm going to experiment with the "multiline" parser and see if I can get that to work.

Comment: Right. Yes, you can experiment with the [`multiline`](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline#formatn) parser plugin. With helm, it'll be easier to generate configuration for that number of lines. However, not sure if the limit of 20 lines (plus first line) would work for you.

Comment: We have mostly single line logs in both json and regex format.  The fluentd source block is configured for "@type tail" and the parse block is configured for "@type multi_format".  I know multi_format and multiline will not work together.  When I tried configuring multiline, none of my single line log files were making it into elasticsearch.  I added the "concat" plugin and am now trying that as a filter.